# Does a function having the property that for every $a_n\rightarrow a$ $f(a_n)$ diverges exist?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

Could you help me solve the following tricky exam problem? Let $f: [
-1, 1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$. Let $a\in [-1, 1]$. Suppose that for every not ultimately constant sequence {$a_n$}, $a_n\in [-1, 1]$, s.t. $a_n\rightarrow a$ the sequence {$f(a_n)$} diverges. Does such a function exist? What if the above condition is true for every point $a\in [-1, 1]$?

I attempted the first part of the problem by setting $f(x) =\frac1x + 1$ for $x\in [-1, 0)$, $f(x) = 0$ for $x = 0$, and $f(x) =\frac1x - 1$ for $x\in(0, 1]$. Then for any sequence converging to $0$, there is no limit for the corresponding values of $f$.

Regarding the second part of the problem, I feel like such a function cannot exist, but I don’t know how to show this. I feel like I need to use Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mittens, take a sequence {$a_n$}, $a_n = \frac1n$. It converges to $0$. Also, $f = 1$ at every point of the sequence and at zero. Thus, $f(a_n) \rightarrow 1$, so it does not satisfy the given condition.

Comment: The sequence of all $a$'s converges to $a$ and $f(a_n)$ cannot diverge

Comment: @Ross Millikan, I’ve forgotten to add the criterion that the sequences in discussion are not ultimately constant. It would make the problem trivial

Comment: Often for such questions it is exactly what you are supposed to realize.

Comment: The sequence $f(a_n)$ can’t be bounded, since if it were bounded there would exist a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ such that $f(a_{n_k})$ converges. But if the sequence $f(a_n)$ is unbounded for every $a$ and $a_n\to a$ that poses problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such function exists; we will show this by contradiction. Assume that $f$ is such a function and let $r > 0$ be such that the set $B = f^{-1}([-r, r])$ is infinite (such an $r$ exists: otherwise $[-1, 1] = \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty f^{-1}([-i, i])$ would imply that $[-1, 1]$ is countable). Take any sequence $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $b_n \in B$ for all $n$ and $b_n \neq b_m$ for $n \neq m$. Now $(f(b_n))_n$ is bounded, so by Bolzano-Weierstrass we find a convergent subsequence $(f(b_{n_k}))_k$. Applying Bolzano-Weierstrass once more to $(b_{n_k})_k$, we find yet another subsequence $(b_{n_{k_l}})_l$ with the property that $(f(b_{n_{k_l}}))_l$ converges, contradiction.

Comment: Good answer. I find the question rather weird IMHO. But this answer is cool.